# $\mathbb{Z}/2\otimes_{\mathbb{ Z}} \mathbb{ Z}$

Tags: tensor-products

What is the tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\mathbb{ Z}$ considered as $\mathbb{ Z}$-modules? That is I want to calculate $\mathbb{Z}/2\otimes_\mathbb{ Z} \mathbb{ Z}$. Is it 0?

Comment: If you have a commutative ring $A$ and an $A$-module $M$ you always get $A \otimes _{A} M \cong M$.

Answer (score 3):

As Stefano says in the comments, for a ring $A$ and an $A$-module $M$, you alwys have $A \otimes_A M \approx M$ via the map $a \otimes m \mapsto am$.

So, in particular, you always have $\mathbb Z/n \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z \approx \mathbb Z/n$.

Comment: that means for any $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, $1\otimes a=1\otimes b$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2 \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}$? How can I prove this?

Comment: No, it is not true. Note that $1 \otimes 2 = 1 \otimes \left( 2 \cdot 1 \right) = \left( 2 \cdot 1 \right) \otimes 1 = 0 \otimes 1 = 0$

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask for any odd integers $a,b$.

Comment: Ok, i think i get it now. They will all be $1\otimes 1$. Thanks so much.